# How to integrate aws device farm into Java code like browserstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-device-farm

I want integrate aws device farm into Java code like browserstack with webdriver .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with browser stack but with device farm you should need to provide the basic capabilities such as device name or app as they're entered on our behalf.

There are some sample web app test packages for python and Java here.

https://github.com/aws-samples?utf8=✓&q=Device+farm+web&type=&language=

Could you let me know of these help answer the question?

Comment: Thanks for answer but I want to automate manual steps like we upload apk file and zip dependency in aws account project. I want to do these steps through Java code. Is there any support provideto do this?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Java sdk to upload and schedule the tests. For examples of what that would look like you can follow the Jenkins plugin example here
https://github.com/awslabs/AWS-device-farm-jenkins-plugin